# Why is my custom form saving with 'autodraft' as title and slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I am currently writing a custom theme from scratch, which utilizes a number of custom post types. I am currently trying to build custom posting forms for them. I have hidden all of the normal form fields, and want the title/slug to populate based on one of the custom fields. So far, the metainformation is saving fin, but the title/slug is always 'autodraft'. Does anybody know how I might fix this?

I have posted the relevant code snippets below.

from functions.php

```
include_once( 'init/custom_post_types.php' );
```

from init/custom_post_types.php

```
function save_custom_post_form( $post ) {
    if( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__  ) . '/../submission_handling/' . $_POST ['post_type'] . '.php' ) )
        include_once( dirname( __FILE__  ) . '/../submission_handling/' . $_POST ['post_type'] . '.php' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_post_form');
```

submission_handling/fixture.php (called when $_POST['post_type'] == 'fixture')

```
<?php
if(basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){exit();}

// save metainformation from custom form. This code works fine

$fixturedate = strtotime( $_POST['fixture-date'] );
update_post_meta($post, 'fixture-date', $fixturedate);
$fixturekickoff = esc_attr( $_POST['fixture-kickoff-time'] );    
update_post_meta($post, 'fixture-kickoff-time', $fixturekickoff);
$fixtureoppteam = esc_attr( $_POST['fixture-opposing-team'] );
update_post_meta($post, 'fixture-opposing-team', $fixtureoppteam);
$fixturepat = esc_attr( $_POST['fixture-player-arrival-time'] );
update_post_meta($post, 'fixture-player-arrival-time', $fixturepat);
$fixtureoppteamurl = esc_attr( $_POST['fixture-opposing-team-website-url'] );       
update_post_meta($post, 'fixture-opposing-team-website-url', $fixtureoppteamurl);
$fixtureaddy = esc_attr( $_POST['fixture-address'] );
update_post_meta($post, 'fixture-address', $fixtureaddy);
$fixface = esc_attr( $_POST['fixture-facebook-event'] );
update_post_meta($post, 'fixture-facebook-event', $fixface);

// Save title and slug into new post. This doesn't seem to work

if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post ) ){
    $posttitle = array (
         'ID' => $post,
         'post_title' => $fixtureoppteam,
         'post_name' => $fixtureoppteam,
     );

     // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
     remove_action('save_post', 'save_custom_post_form');

     // update the post, which calls save_post again
     wp_update_post( $posttitle );


     // re-hook this function
     add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_post_form');
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, with a bit of debugging, I have worked out that wp_is_post_revision( $post ) is returning the post ID of $post, which is why the post updating code is not firing.

After looking at the raw database I have worked out the following.

When I add a new post, TWO entries are made in the database, with statuses of 'inherit' and 'publish' respectively. It seems that $post is taking the id of the 'inherit' post, which is why `wp_is_post_revision ( $post )` is failing. The odd thing is that all those `update_post_meta ( ... )` entries are also using `$post` but the meta entries end up linked to the correct post (the 'publish' post).

I still have no idea how to solve this problem without removing the `wp_is_post_revision ( $post )` check, which I don't think is a great idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after reading the codex page on the 'save_post' hook, I spotted that they use a different way of dealing with revisions. So removing the `if {...}` surrounding the `wp_update_post( $posttitle )` and inserting the following code fixed my problem:

```
if ( $post = wp_is_post_revision( $post ) )
        $post = $post;
```